# Javascript object key is not accessible

Tags: javascript, tizen, tizen-emulator

I am using the Samsung Tizen SDK for SmartTV app development. I have some code that converts CSV to a Javascript object. I am having problems accessing one of the keys in the object that is created from the code.

Code:

```
function csvJSON(csv) {

var lines = csv.split("\n");

var result = [];

var headers = lines[0].split(",");

for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {


    var obj = {startTime:'',
            endTime:'',
            day:''};

    var currentline = lines[i].split(",");

    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }

    result.push(obj);

}

return result; // JavaScript object
```

}

My inputs to this function look like: 
[Input to function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXHRq.png)

While debugging the return result line in the console developer mode (I set a local watch of obj.endTime), I cannot access the endTime key, despite it showing up in the debugger. It is almost as if a special character is involved somehow.

[endTime key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i67H7.png)

I tried the same snippet of code in jsFiddle and it worked ... so it seems like something related to the version of Javascript/ECMAScript that is running on the Tizen Emulator. Perhaps this was an issue in earlier versions of Javascript ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered that your header has an encoding issue?

Comment: Are you saying it does have an encoding issue or that it might?

Comment: I don't know. I would check that your `'endTime' === 'endTime'`. Perhaps you have some characters that only appear to be equal, but the are really some non-ascii unicode character that only apear to be a ascii character. One example of such a character of the top of my head would be [NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) or [FULLWIDTH LATIN SMALL LETTER E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff45/index.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check that `endTime` in your csv header is truly equal to `endtime`, i.e.

```js
endTime1 = 'endTime'
endTime2 = '\uff45ndTime'
console.log(`${endTime1} equals ${endTime2} is ${endTime1 === endTime2}`)
// endTime equals ｅndTime is false

obj = {}
obj[endTime1] = 'endTime1'
obj[endTime2] = 'endTime2'
console.log(obj)
// {
//   "endTime": "endTime1",
//   "ｅndTime": "endTime2"
// }
```

Any reason why you are not using a library for this?, e.g.
http://papaparse.com/docs#csv-to-json

Comment: I ended up switching to PapaParse with good results. Thank you!